# Can Sybase CASE expressions have a default column name for their result?

Tags: mysql, sql, sybase

I have a sybase query that is structured like this:

```
SELECT 
    case 
        when isnull(a,'') <> '' then a
        else convert(varchar(20), b)
    end 
FROM table_name
WHERE b=123
```

It used to return the results of the 'case' in a column named 'converted'.  It now returns the results of the 'case' in a column with an empty string name ''.

How could this be? Could there be some database configuration that defaults the results of a 'case' with no name?

(I've fixed the broken query by adding " as computed" after 'end' but now I'd like to know how it used to return as 'computed' before I added the fix?)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT (case when isnull(a, '') <> '' then a
             else convert(varchar(20), b)
        end) as converted
-------------^
FROM table_name
WHERE b = 123;
```

By the way, you could write the `select` more succinctly as:

```
SELECT coalesce(nullif(a, ''), b) as converted
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not what I'm looking for.  I'm simply asking if there could be some database configuration that defaults the results of a 'case' with no name.

Comment: @JayB . . . I have never heard of such a configuration parameter in any database.